# ADT building ANE Error: ... have conflicting package paths

Tags: intellij-idea, air, adobe, adt, ane

Trying to build an adobe air ANE (Native iOS Extension) it fails while packaging the ANE with ADT. The error says conflicting package paths but i don't know which paths are meant?!

The Terminal Input:

```
adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc iBeacon-ANE_Air.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -C ios . -platformoptions platformoptions.xml . -platform default -C default .
```

The Terminal Output (Error):

```
Files "/Volumes/Lion/Users/.../Documents/.../iBeacons/build/ios/libiBeacon-ANE.a" and "/Volumes/Lion/Users/.../Documents/.../iBeacons/build/ios/libiBeacon-ANE.a" have conflicting package paths: /Volumes/Lion/Users/.../Documents/.../iBeacons/build/ios/libiBeacon-ANE.a
```

("..." in the paths are private parts)

Answer (score 0):

adt –package –storetype pkcs12 –keystore cert.p12 –storepass XXXX –target ane Name.ane extension.xml –swc Name.swc –platform iPhone-ARM –C iOS . –platformoptions ios/platformoptions.xml –platform Android-ARM –C android . –platform default –C default .

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2482335412ffea65006-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and I find the problem is the extra " ." in the command line! just change your command from:

```
adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc iBeacon-ANE_Air.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -C ios . -platformoptions platformoptions.xml . -platform default -C default .
```

to:

```
adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc iBeacon-ANE_Air.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -C ios . -platformoptions platformoptions.xml -platform default -C default .
```

and it will work!